# How to handle filenames with unicode characters in VBA using Dir?

Tags: vba, excel, unicode

I am selecting a list of files based on a criteria using Dir, and then storing these in an array of strings. I then iterate through the array and process the files.

How can i handle filenames with unicode characters?

I tried to do `StrConv` but it didn't help.

```
vfile = Dir(vCurrDir & vCrit, vbNormal) 'vCrit is something like *test*
```

Then later I'll try to access the file's properties like this:

```
vfilename = vCurrDir & "\" & vfile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
vDateMod = objFSO.GetFile(vfilename).datelastmodified
```

at the last line I get an error-message that the File is not found. This only happens for filenames with unicode characters.

There was another post regarding this here: [Working with Unicode file names in VBA (using Dir, FileSystemObject, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685990/working-with-unicode-file-names-in-vba-using-dir-filesystemobject-etc), but it didn`t solve the problem with`Dir`.

My Example:
VBA (watch) c:\my-test-file.pdf Unicode: c:\my‐test‐file.pdf

(you cannot see the difference here but if you copy the names and paste them into Notepad++ you'll see that the dashes are different characters for the two files, VBA is converting the unicode dash character into a windows locale dash)

Or the example from the linked question:
3_Połish.txt (in Unicode) vs 3_Polish.txt (in VBA)

Comment: Did you try to add a watch on your `vfilename`? What is displayed?

Comment: Yes of course, VBA is converting the file name to windows locale: (you cannot see it here but the dashes are different between the two filenames, if you copy paste to Notepad++ you`ll see what i mean) VBA (watch)
c:\my-test-file.pdf

Unicode:
c:\my‐test‐file.pdf

Comment: Did you try using `fso.GetFolder(path)`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Using FileSystemObject to crawl through subdirectories for files was much too slow. For my needs, I coded the creation and running of a batch file that, among other things, used the `Dir` command and piped the output to a file. Then after the batch file completed, my code parsed the output file. Weirdly, unicode characters were just fine, and then suddenly they weren't. (I never tried to figure out why. I'm guessing it was either because we moved the files to a different place, I started using a client instead of a server to do the processing, or the Win10 upgrade du jour, but none of these were within my control.)

The way I solved it was to change the creation of the batch file from including a `dir` command to instead execute a DOS command of `call cmd /u /c dir "dirpath" > c:\Temp\DirOutput.txt` and then read the file.

- `cmd /u` is the key part. This forces the output piped to a file to be in Unicode
- `call` because it was within a batch file, and `call` pauses batch file execution until the command is complete. Not needed for a simple `dir` but I found it needed for `cmd`. (Maybe there was a better way, but this is the one I stumbled on first.)
- The `/c` flag of `cmd` tells `cmd` to treat the rest of the line as a command to execute, then terminate.
- `dir` can also have flags, of course. I used a `/s` flag because I needed all files within *and below* `dirpath`
- `>` to tell `dir` to output the results to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem lies in the use of `Dir` to create the list of files, instead, I suggest a wider use of the `FileSystemObject`, i.e.: the properties of its `Folder` and `File` objects.

The procedure below prints the properties `Name`, `DateLastModified` and `Path` for all `txt` files in folder `D:\@D_Trash\`

```
Sub Files_with_Unicode_Chars()
Dim oFso As Object      'Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim oFdr As Object      'Scripting.Folder
Dim oFle As Object      'Scripting.File
Dim vCurrDir As String, vCrit As String

    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    vCurrDir = "D:\@D_Trash\"   'Update as needed!
    vCrit = ".txt"              'Update as needed!

    Set oFdr = oFso.GetFolder(vCurrDir)
    For Each oFle In oFdr.Files
        With oFle
            Select Case Mid(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, "."))
            Case vCrit
                Rem Perform actions as needed
                Rem This sample shows the use some of the File object properties
                Debug.Print Now; vbTab; "["; .Name; "]"; Tab(71); .DateLastModified; Tab(101); .Path
    End Select: End With: Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use BuildPath https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251615.aspx instead of

```
vfilename = vCurrDir & "\" & vfile
```