# How to read / write binary file with Unicode filename in VB6

Tags: unicode, vb6, filenames

I have this code:

```vb
Function cpyBIN(cpFilename As String)
    Dim litefile() As Byte
    Dim FN As Integer
    Dim xlof As Long

    FN = 1
    Open cpFilename For Binary As FN
    xlof = LOF(FN)
    ReDim litefile(xlof)

    Get FN, , litefile
    Open cpFilename & "Backup" For 
    Binary As #2

    Put #2, , litefile
    Close #2
    Close FN
End Function
```

and I use it in a Form like this :

```vb
Private Sub cmdBackup_Click()
Dim strComputer, objWMIService, colFiles, objfile

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_Datafile where Drive='D:' and path='\\contoh\\'")

For Each objfile In colFiles
cpyBIN (objfile.Name)
Next


End Sub
```

in the **contoh** folder there are 2 sample files:

- namafile.exe
- namafile♣♣♠.exe

when I run the code there is an error message like in the picture:

[image]

the error is in the line as shown in the picture:

[image]

how to make it supports unicode filename?
or
is there any replacement for this function??

Comment: What error message do you get and on what line?

Comment: Exactly how does it fail? You said it does not work but that isn't very specific...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with Unicode file names in VBA (using Dir, FileSystemObject, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685990/working-with-unicode-file-names-in-vba-using-dir-filesystemobject-etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type currency symbols in Visual Basic Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24384952/11683)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and fixing my question.
sorry if my question is difficult to understand because my english is not good. I have updated my question. I hope friends can help

Comment: @enddieonskynet Your question was fine. Arguably, you've made it more difficult to understand with your last edit. There will always be people who are not competent enough to understand your question, just learn to ignore them. Please see the dupe links that together answer your question. `Open` does not support Unicode file names, and you cannot reliably have Unicode string literals in the code editor.

Comment: so what command should I use? if it is open it doesn't support unicode.
the point is to be able to read files with unicode names.

Comment: You could declare the "Kernel" copy methods and use windows instead ... should make all encoding work -> see my answer for this (coming in 5 minutes)

Comment: @enddieonskynet Have you tried to actually look at the links?

Comment: I had remove my answer - must check it first on my vb6 system (currently in the office ... can do this later in the evening)

Comment: @enddieonskynet Do you need to read the file, or simply make a copy of the file?

Comment: @GSerg i want to read binary

Comment: @nabuchodonossor thanks for your efforts. I'm waiting for the answer

Comment: @Brian M Stafford
i want to read binary from file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to make a copy of a file with Unicode file names.  The first way is by using the **Windows API**:

```
Declare Function CopyFileW Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpExistingFileName As Long, _
   ByVal lpNewFileName As Long, Optional ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long

For Each objfile In colFiles
   CopyFileW StrPtr(objfile.Name), StrPtr(objfile.Name & ".Backup")
Next
```

The second way is by using a **FileSystemObject**:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

For Each objfile In colFiles
   fso.CopyFile objfile.Name, objfile.Name & ".Backup", True
Next
```

The third way is by using an **ADO Stream**:

```
Dim s As ADODB.Stream
Set s = New ADODB.Stream
   
s.Open
s.Type = adTypeBinary

For Each objFile In colFiles
   s.LoadFromFile objFile.Name
   s.SaveToFile objFile.Name & ".Backup", adSaveCreateOverWrite
Next

s.Close
```

If you want to read data, I would use an ADO Stream:

```
Dim s As ADODB.Stream
Set s = New ADODB.Stream

s.Open
s.Type = adTypeBinary

For Each objFile In colFiles
   s.LoadFromFile objFile.Name
   data = s.Read()
   'use the data somehow
Next

s.Close
```

Comment: thanks your code works fine.
but I want to not just copy. but can read files?

Comment: @enddieonskynet I updated my answer to show how to read binary files.

Comment: sorry what reference should i use? I got an error message:
Compile Error: User-Defined Type Not Defined

Comment: @enddieonskynet Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library.

Comment: yes!

it really works.
I can only say thank you very much.

Comment: @enddieonskynet: Sorry for late answer, have no VB6 @ the office, only on my private pc. Was now able to check the CopyFileW version -> as Gserg pointed out

Comment: @nabuchodonossor  it is okay

Comment: @Brian M Stafford
now i found a new problem.

this code:
`Dim s As ADODB.Stream
Set s = New ADODB.Stream

s.Open
s.Type = adTypeBinary

For Each objFile In colFiles
   s.LoadFromFile objFile.Name
   data = s.Read()
   'use the data somehow
Next

s.Close`

does not support large files.
I got the error message "not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation"

Comment: You will need to read the file in chunks.  Notice that the `Read` method takes a parameter for number of bytes to read.