# Format Data Type of Selected Cells in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the data type of the selected cells using VBA and my current code is not working. I'm looping through multiple Excel files in a directory but it seems like the current code either doesn't open the workbook or save the change in the end.

I want to open each Excel file, change the data type of the two selected cell, and save the change.
Here's the code I have now:

```
Sub Formatting()
Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String


MyFolder = "C:\Users\Documents\Files"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

    Range("G4").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("E4").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    Workbooks(MyFile).Save
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the workbook object into a variable, and then use that with the `ActiveSheet.Range`.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Do While MyFile <> ""

    Debug.Print MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
    wb.Activesheet.Range("G4").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    wb.Activesheet.Range("E4").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

<sub>Note: if there is more than one sheet, whichever one is active will get the change. If there is a better way to identify the sheet, then use that instead of ActiveSheet.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, the code itself doesn't raise an error message but still doesn't make any change. The file names contain some foreign alphabet other than English alphabets and I wonder maybe that's why the loop doesn't recognize each file in the directory.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `MyFolder = "C:\Users\Documents\Files"` - it's missing the user name, unless your user name is `Documents`.

Comment: I added a debug line, so it will show you the document name in the immediate window. If it never shows anything, then it's not even using the loop because `MyFile` is already an empty string.

Comment: The directory name is correct. I deleted my username to exclude the private information. I have the correct directory path in my code. I included the debug line and it didn't work. It just seems like VBA is not working or something. It doesn't raise any error but also doesn't make any changes.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" do you mean "nothing was printed to the immediate window"? I still say it's a problem with your `MyFolder`. If you paste `C:\Users\Documents\Files` into your windows explorer, do the files you want appear? Use your Windows Explorer to locate the folder, and then copy the full path from the top of it instead.

Comment: @ braX yes, nothing was printed to the window. And yes, when I paste my directory into the windows explorer, I can see the full list of the files. Maybe something's wrong with my Excel setting.

Comment: It's not an Excel setting. Try it like this: `MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls*")` and/or put a `MsgBox MyFile` after you set it to see what you get. I bet it is blank the way you have it now. If it's blank that means it did not find any files there.

Comment: Thanks. Previously, the excel file that has the macro was saved outside of the folder that has all the source files. So I moved the excel file with the macro into the source folder and now I'm getting this error message: Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted. I think it is because file names contain some foreign characters.

Comment: Are those characters paste-able here?

Comment: For example, something like 会议记录. I believe it's Chinese.

Comment: `Dir` does not support Unicode characters. You can use the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) instead to get the file names from the folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685990/working-with-unicode-file-names-in-vba-using-dir-filesystemobject-etc

Comment: Your question really would be something like how to use unicode filenames characters in VBA, now that you see how to handle the range in the looping part.