GetFile doesn't work with files which names contain of special characters
I have a VBA macro that loops through the files in a specified path, chooses the file with the newest date and writes the path of the file into a variable "FileToCopy".
Unfortunately if the newest file contains any special characters (in my case it's a letter: "ż"), VBA reads it as "z". So a file "sprzedaż" becomes "sprzedaz". Then this line of code:
FileCopy FiletoCopy, Destination 

fails the macro, because there isn't a file in the system called "sprzedaz". So I get "File not found" error.
I tried to use CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(FileToCopy) but I suppose it works the same way, because same error appears.
I have also found another thread on stackoverlow with someone having the same problem and it was solved by using Chr function, but when I check the character list there is no "ż", which is the only letter I need: (Link_to_character_list). So I can't use this solution.
The entire code works perfect when ż is not there, so I really just a need to know how to copy a file with such character.

It would help to update your post with the code leading up to the FileCopy line you posted.

^^^ Indeed, maybe you can use ChrW$(&H17C) instead of ż ? This and this may be of use

See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685990/working-with-unicode-file-names-in-vba-using-dir-filesystemobject-etc

FSO can handle this - if I create a file with the same name "sprzedaż.xlsx" then this code:
Dim fso As Object, f
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Temp\").Files
    If f.Name Like "sprz*" Then
        [A1].Value = f.Name
        f.Copy "C:\Temp\sprzedaz2.xlsx"
        Exit For
    End If
Next f

...put that name in A1 and created a copy.

Thank you!
So... In my code before I used FileCopy FileToCopy, Destination where "FileToCopy" was a String variable with a path to the file. This didn't work at all. Writing FileCopy fso.GetFile(FileToCopy), Destination also throws the same error.
However!
fso.GetFile(FileToCopy).Copy Destination - works beautifully!
Do you have any idea why FileCopy command doesn't work, but simple Copy does?
Also, I didn't put the name of the file to A1 or any other cell because it seems unnecessary. After all you are not referencing this cell at all at the end of the loop.
Thank you once again

I only put the file name into a cell as a check, because the alternative checks (Debug.Print or MsgBox) do not work with special characters.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33693022/478884   I can't say specifically why filecopy is different from FSO other than to note that parts of VBA are quite old, and FSO is newer...

Yeah, that's what I thought - that cell value is only a check. However, previously, when I put my FileToCopy String into a cell it also displayed ż correctly, and FileCopy command still didn't work so it's not a valid check. Similarly to the post you linked I have already found a few cases where people claim that FileCopy doesn't work with certain characters while using fso and then "Copy" works easily. I guess it's a better method after all. Once again - thank you very very much!
